# C# Winforms DataGridView Setting the Fore and BackColor style of specific columns of the selected row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataSet`. Two of the columns in the `DataGridView` are status columns (MatchStatus, EscalationStatus), which change fore and back color depending on the content of the cells in those columns. When the user selects a row, the entire row changes to white text on blue background. This is fine, but I want the two status columns to retain their custom colours. Currently I'm doing this in the `CellFormatting` event.

Setting up the grid:

```
                grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
                grid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
                grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                grid.ReadOnly = true;
                grid.MultiSelect = false;
                grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                grid.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleVertical;
                grid.Columns.Clear();

... load data ...

                grid.DataSource = _somedata;
                grid.Refresh();
```

CellFormatting event:

```
        private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "MatchStatus") ||
                (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "EscalationStatus"))
            {
                switch (grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "UNTESTED":
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        break;

                    case "CCR EXPIRED":
                    case "GBR EXPIRED":
                    case "LIMIT MISMATCH":
                    case "EXPIRY MISMATCH":
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                        break;

                    case "LIMIT EXPIRED":
                    case "LIMIT EXCEEDED":
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        break;

                    default:
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I retain the formatting of just those two columns when the row is selected?

Comment: Set the same color for `e.CellStyle.BackColor` and `e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor`. Do the same for the foreground colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment above by @dr.null (all credit to them), the answer is:

"Set the same color for e.CellStyle.BackColor and e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor. Do the same for the foreground colors."